# iPhone:Sqlite file not found in library documents

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I am trying some DB based apps in iphone.I used this [sample](http://iphonetut.com/sqlite/137/insert_data_into_database%28sqlite%29_in_iphone) as a guide and it works nice.
When I start a new project,no data is displayed.When checked I found that the sqlite file is not available in the library folder.

I checked the DBpath but its right.
What's gone wrong ?Please help me..

Comment: have you included a sqlite file in your resources folder...?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Yes I included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_%28Xcode_4%29) 
You need to set the path for the sqlite3.h file my using

```
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

Hope this will help you out :)